# Getting the following error: SQL 80001 Incorrect syntax near "Natural"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having issues with the following code and I have attached the two pieces of code I am working with as well as the error I am getting.
Here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_rentalandemployees    
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Rental_ID, Rental_Start_Date, Rental_End_Date,
        Rental_Type_Description,  
        Employee_id, Employee_First_Name, Employee_Last_Name,
        COUNT(VIN) AS Vehicle_count    
    FROM 
        Rentals R 
    INNER JOIN 
        Rental_Types RT ON R.Rental_Type = Rental_type_Id    
    INNER JOIN 
        Employees E ON E.Employee_id = R.Rental_Employee_Id    
    NATURAL JOIN
        Rental_Vehicles RV    
    GROUP BY 
        Rental_ID
END;
```

Here is the second piece I am working with:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Rental_repair_cost    
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Rental_ID, Rental_Start_Date, Rental_End_Date,
        SUM(ISNULL(Repair_cost, 0)) AS Total_repair_cost    
    FROM 
        Rentals R
    NATURAL JOIN 
        Rental_vehicles    
    WHERE 
        Rental_Type_Description = 'Personal'
END;
```

Here are the errors:

> SQL 80001: Incorrect syntax near 'Natural'.       Miscellaneous     SQL.query5.sql     10
> SQL 80001: Incorrect syntax near 'Natural'.       Miscellaneous     SQL.query7.sql      7

Comment: Where did you hear about a natural join? Its not a SQL Server thing...

Comment: I have been getting help on Chegg and that is how they helped me.

Comment: It doesn't exist on SQL Server...

Comment: how could I fix it to make the code above work?

Comment: Just use a regular join?

Comment: This isn't you are well is it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64885072/ms-sql-error-msg-207-level-16-state-1-procedure-hw4select7-line-15-invalid-co

Comment: No. It is not...

Answer (score 0):

Happily, SQL Server doesn't support `NATURAL JOIN`.  So you need an explicit `ON` condition:

```
SELECT Rental_ID, Rental_Start_Date, Rental_End_Date,
       SUM(COALESCE(Repair_cost,0)) as Total_repair_cost    
FROM Rentals R JOIN
     Rental_vehicles    
     ON R.Vehicle_ID = rv.Vehicle_ID -- guessing at the condition
WHERE Rental_Type_Description = 'Personal';
```

Note that there is nothing "natural" about so-called `natural join`s.  In particular, they depend only on columns having the same name -- and they don't take advantage of properly declared foreign key relationships.  I would suggest that you simply forget that some databases support them.